# Create bar plot with ggplot2 but plot won't produce?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate a bar plot for the count of workers per salary for each site. The data frame is called "salary_scales_counts_by_site".

| Site | Managing Operator | Operations Technician | Process Engineer | Senior Process Engineer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cork | 12 | 16 | 12 | 11 |
| LA | 6 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| Dublin | 13 | 17 | 6 | 16 |

I have tried several formulas but something is always missing, I'm going crazy cos I still have to make 4 other graphs that will probably by shambolic too. Any help is much appreciated!

```
ggplot(salary_scale_counts_by_site, aes(x = salary_scale_counts_by_site, y = `Managing Operator`)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "green") +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", x = salary_scale_counts_by_site, y = `Operations Technician`, fill = "blue") +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", x = salary_scale_counts_by_site, y = `Process Engineer`, fill = "orange") +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", x = salary_scale_counts_by_site, y = `Senior Process Engineer`, fill = "purple") +
   xlab("Site") +
   ylab("Count") +
   labs(title = "Count of Managing Operators, Operations Technicians, Process Engineers, and Senior Process Engineers per site") +
   theme_classic()
```

This looks alright to me but I got the following error:

```
Error: object 'Operations Technician' not found
```

I just want a bar chart that shows each site and the number of people working under each scale (named as the job title).

Comment: Any reference to variables need to be within `aes()`.

Comment: Phil is correct. It would be helpful if you could post your actual data set (use `dput(salary_scale_counts_by_site)`). Lastly, you will have an easier time with ggplot if you transform your data into a long format (see `tidyr::pivot_longer()`).

Comment: More specifically (on Phil's comment), you need `aes(x=.., y=..)`, whereas the `stat=` and `fill=` should stay outside of `aes(..)`.

Answer (score 3):

ggplot works best when your data are in good shape.

So first you need to rearrange them:

```
x <- salary_scale_counts_by_site %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -Site, names_to = "job_title", values_to = "counts")
```

| Site | job_title | counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cork | Managing Operator | 12 |
| Cork | Operations Technician | 16 |
| Cork | Process Engineer | 12 |
| Cork | Senior Process Engineer | 11 |
| LA | Managing Operator | 6 |
| LA | Operations Technician | 2 |
| LA | Process Engineer | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Now as you want bars for site and job you need to combine bars:

```
ggplot(x, aes(x = job_title, y = counts)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(vars(Site), nrow = 1)
```

[image]

It needs some polishing, but you got the idea.